# Product Image problems

Tags: product-images

The image of the product will show when on the actual product page and it is the only product on the page but when on you search the SKU there is no thumbnail picture or when scrolling or browsing on a category page, product photos do not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the thumbnail of product image. Open any product check options as showing in given [picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPH3z.png)

Comment: The thumbnail selection is selected and still no thumbnail image shows up, just a magento symbol in faded grey shows up on the site when you search the SKU or product.